# Groupby a single column and split into different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (shown below)that has a owner column and I want to groupby owner and save those into different dataframes ( the end goal is to convert df to html tables). Below is the solution I have tried.

| Person | Number | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 849732 | atlanta |
| Ali | 87543 | denver |
| John | 873543 | knoxville |
| Ali | 898779 | aspen |
| Sam | 875435 | nashville |

I want to create separate dfs for John, Ali and Sam.

```
res = dict(tuple(df.groupby('Person')))
listing = list (res)
for l in listing:
   new_df = res[l]
   print(new_df)
```

My problem is I end up with a list of data frames after doing this and I am having trouble into splitting them into separate data frames that can be converted to html files. Perhaps something like this might work but I am missing some logic because I only get one df instead of looping through and getting multiples.

```
 for owner in new_df:
        html = df.to_html()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches to this. The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/groupby.html) might help.

The GroupBy object returned by `groupby()` supports iteration. It produces tuples of the form `(name, subset)` where subset here is each dataframe you are looking for. So your code could just look something like:

```
html_by_owner = {}
for owner, new_df in df.groupby('Person'):
    html_by_owner[owner] = new_df.to_html()
```

Comment: When I try to run this code, this still gives me df for only one of the owners because the new_df only shows me one owner in the df. Am I missing something?

Comment: I thought you wanted a separate data frame for each owner? This iterates over each of them. On each iteration new_df will be a different data frame, one for each owner.